# Remove <thead> if there are no <tbody> rows on the same page

Tags: html, css

I have a multi-page document, which have multiple tables and pages. I am trying to ensure that if that there are no tbody rows in that page, it doesnt display the thead. However I am facing scenarios where the thead headers display even when there are no tbody rows, just leaving the header at the bottom of the page.

I have tried using "page-break-inside: avoid;" on the whole table, but if that table has too many rows, it will just bring the entire table to the next page instead of cutting it in the middle.

Using the normal "page-break-inside: auto;", i get the same problem where the  displays even when there are no tbody rows on the same page

```
table#transaction-table {
    page-break-inside: auto;
}

<table id="transaction-table">
<thead>
<tr><td>row1</td></tr>
<tr><th>row2a</th><th>row2b</th></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<!-- bunch of data -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

I expect the thead not to show if there are no tbody rows on the same page, but it is just showing a thead row with no data underneath it

Comment: What determines whether there are rows or not? Can you not use whatever logic determines to out the rows to add a class to the table?  when the class appears, hide the <thead> via CSS.

Comment: there will always be rows. just that on some pages, the 1st table is having enough rows that for the 2nd table only the thead fits at the bottom of the page. so this ends up just making the 2nd table have the thead displayed, and on the following page the thead again with the tbody data.